# Show/Hide Divs W/ Pure JQuery via Links

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I am in search of a way to show and hide div's repeatably using only JQuery via links. I have written out an example bellow.

```
<div id="section1">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>

<div id="section2">
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
<div>
```

In this above situation let's assume section 2 is hidden on the page load. How am I able to show section 2 and hide section 1 when the Google link is clicked then re-show section 1 and hide section 2 when the Yahoo link is clicked?

I have sort of accomplished this already however it includes a ton of hefty scripting (javascript) and does not work in Internet Explorer, which is the main problem.

Thanks for all the help! I appreciate it greatly!!!

Comment: Post your javascript. Cut out the relevant part and paste it into your question. We can't help you fix your code unless you show it.

Comment: I am actually looking for a brand new way of doing this. I have a way that sort of works however does not work at all in Internet Explorer. If I were to fix my current way to include more div's it still would not function correctly in IE.

Comment: dont forget to mark answwer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something similar to this based on [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#section1').show();
    $('#section2').hide();

    $('#section1 a').click(function() {
        $('#section1').hide('fast');
        $('#section2').show('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $('#section2 a').click(function() {
        $('#section2').hide('fast');
        $('#section1').show('fast');
        return false;
    });

});
```

I haven't tested it, might need revising and can probably be shortened. More info here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [**`.hide()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [**`.show()`**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method available in jQuery library will do your task...

or make use of [**`.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which handle task easily..

```
$('#section1 a').click(function(){
    $('#section1').hide();
    $('#section2').show();
});
$('#section2 a').click(function(){
    $('#section2').hide();
    $('#section1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how to use show() and hide() to do what you're asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZvB7X/1

and here's the relevant jQuery (you'll need to view the jsfiddle to see it accompanied by the css and markup which needn't be repeated here.)

```
$('#section1 a').click(function(){
    $('#section1').hide();
    $('#section2').show();
});

$('#section2 a').click(function(){
    $('#section2').hide();
    $('#section1').show();
});​
```